# how to make the icon.png be shown with older iphones and the icon@2x.png a newer ones?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, retina-display

I have made 2 icons, one 57x57 for older iPhones without retina display, and other 114x114 for retina ones. On the info.plist I put the icon file = icon.png, and now? Where I put the icon@2x.png and where i define witch one will be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in xcode 4.5 and so on you do not need to manually add the icon.png's in the info .plist anymore. or at least that is what i gathered. here is the step by step of the stuff you have to do.

- in xcode when project is open look at the right side pane where all the classes are.
- click on the name of the project (hilighted in blue)
- then on the next pane select the target ( usually the name of the project again)
- make sure summery is selected from the top of the screen
- scroll down until you see two empty squares that are representing the icons you have to use.
- if you hover your mouse over them it shows what icon has to go where. ( 57 X 57 goes to the left square)
- drag the icon png file and drop it in the square it belong and follow the same step for the @2x.png.

now if you go to your ufo.plist file you see that the icons included in the icon section.

hope this helps

adrian

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple icon files in your info plist with the [CFBundleIconFiles](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW10) key. `CFBundleIconFiles`contains an array of strings identifying the icon files for the bundle. The system automatically chooses the most appropriately sized icon based on the usage and the underlying device type.

Moreover, if you do not specify the  filename extension of your icon filenames, you can omit high-resolution variants of your image files. The system automatically detects high-resolution (`@2x`) versions of your image files. In other words, if you specify "icon" instead of "icon.png" in your info plist, and you also have a high-resolution version named "icon@2x.png" in your project (and copied into the app bundle), you don't even need to specify "icon@2x.png" in the info plist.

For information about the icons, including their sizes, see ["App Icons"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW2) in *iOS Human Interface Guidelines*.

Answer (score 0):

rather using the info.plist just drag your icon and drop in the placement that it has in the target level of the project. xcode will automatically add them to the info.plist

hope this helps

adrian

Comment: "in the placement that it has in the target level of the project"? Sorry, but i didn't understand...